# Spark: Concatenating lists?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to concatenate all lists in:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[Record]]
```

to get a single collection:

```
val values: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Record]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`flatMap` that!

```
val rdd : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[Record]] = ???

val flattened = rdd.flatMap(identity)
```

Where `identity` is the identity function `f(x) => x`